# In Rails, how do I go over a db migration without executing it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rake, rails-migrations

So I jumped onto this Rails project at work and I have my own copy of it running on my local devbox. I tried to run the tests to see what the results were but rake came back complaining that I had 5 outstanding migrations to do first. I first just tried running `rake db:migrate` but that didn't work due to the migrations trying to create tables that already existed. It was then I realized that these migrations have already been run, but for some reason it thinks it is currently at an older migration.

Is there any way to make Rake move forward in the migration history without doing a rollback and redoing the migration?

Comment: Out of interest you could try and execute the following `rake db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:migrate` in your command prompt

Comment: run `rake db:test:prepare` that should bring the test db up to the same migrations as the development db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update schema_migrations table to have the migration numbers that you want to skip. That's the table rails uses to keep track of the migrations that have been run already.

```
select * from schema_migrations
```

will give you something like

```
   version     
----------------
 20121026165533
 20121026183631
 20121212144141
 20130205205009
```

Add the migration numbers that you want to skip to this table.

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

1. Delete the migrations in question, make a new set of migrations to take their place (dangerous)
2. Do the rake db:reset as you mentioned.

I would only suggest 1 if you are the only developer on the project. In reality however, your migrations and seeds should be in such a state as to not warrant this.

I would implore you to take #2, as #1 could result in issues down the track. Your copy of the database should be representative of what you would get if you ran rake db:reset anyway.